# Regular expression for @RequestMapping() in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to access the method only if the vegetable names are not carrot or beans or onions so if I give tomato it should return the view. I'm using the Url as below is there anything wrong in this url?

```
@RequestMapping("/**/vegetables/{name:^[carrot|beans|onions]}")
public String vegetablesNames(){
    return "vegetables";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get it as @PathVariable and check inside a function? RegExp is a huge thing, I'd rather avoid them If I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should validate inside the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/vegetables/{name}")
public String vegetablesNames(@PathVariable String name){

    if (name.matches("your regex") {
        throw new RuntimeException(name + " doesn't match");
    }
    return "vegetables";
}
```

`@PathVarialbe` is the variable extracted from the request `URI`. You can extract it and play with it as you wish.

Basically the path should describe the resource that is available at that uri. If the resource isn't available, the response should be e.g. `NOT_FOUND`. In `Spring`, default response to the request which caused `RuntimeException` is `5xx` which isn't good choice in this case, but this is just an example.

If you're interested in handling `Exceptions` in `Spring`, just ask for clarification.

Comment: Exactly. IMHO the path should describe the general format, but contain no business (or validation) logic. The validation inside can be made with regex, comparing to a list, checked against database etc. and it will be a lot easier to change that rather than the path variable.